# How to get a list of custom Powershell functions?

Tags: powershell

I use custom powershell functions to make my life easier.

Example:

```
# custom function
> function build {cmd /c build.ps1}

# invoke the function
> build
```

This works great to allow me to run my build script quickly.
Unfortunately it's easy to forget all of the custom functions that I've created.

Is there a cmdlet that I can run to dump a list of my custom functions? Subsequently, once I know what those functions are, is there a cmdlet that I can run to delete ones that I no longer need?

Comment: and which command shows the location path=definition of it? In Linux this seems not possible, command which does it show for cmdlets (e.g. which dir = /bin/dir), but not for custom functions

Comment: Why aren't you dot sourcing build.ps1, i.e. `. .\build.ps1` to define the functions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To get a list of available functions

```
> Get-ChildItem function:\
```

To remove a powershell function

```
# removes `someFunction`
> Remove-Item function:\someFunction
```

Comment: Be careful: only for the current session, to use it forever see @mjolinor s answer.

Answer (score 12):

Add this to your profile:

```
$sysfunctions = gci function:
function myfunctions {gci function: | where {$sysfunctions -notcontains $_} }
```

and myfunctions will list just the functions that were created since the session started.

Comment: Works nicely but needs to be added at the start of your profile, before your custom functions

Comment: Stops working if you use `. $profile` to reload recent changes. Guess it considers the "reload" a new session

Comment: @KolobCanyon No, it doesn't consider anything a "new session." It just re-runs the `gci function:` command; the return value includes all your custom functions at the time you call `. $profile`. A potential fix could be to wrap `$sysfunctions = gci function:` inside an `if` block that ensures it doesn't already have a value.

Comment: To complement if you want to see all your functions, just put this at the beginning of `$profile`: `function myfunctions {gci function: }`

Comment: Really sweet :)

Answer (score 6):

I didn't like the answers given, because for some reason, I did not see my custom functions from my profile listed when I called `Get-ChildItem function:` so here's what I made:

```
Function Get-MyCommands {
    Get-Content -Path $profile | Select-String -Pattern "^function.+" | ForEach-Object {
        # Find function names that contains letters, numbers and dashes
        [Regex]::Matches($_, "^function ([a-z0-9.-]+)","IgnoreCase").Groups[1].Value
    } | Where-Object { $_ -ine "prompt" } | Sort-Object
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I edited to create an alias-like command to list function definitions as well: `$funcs = Get-Content...` and then `foreach ($x in $funcs) { $y=(Get-ChildItem function:$x).scriptblock; echo $x=$y }`

Comment: This is a good solution. I liked the simple approach of just filtering the content from the default profile.

Comment: In hindsight I should probably use AST instead of regex, but meh, whatever, it works

Comment: Also, I've slightly changed the regex expression so it doesn't cut the numbers: `^function ([a-z0-9.-]+)`

Comment: @ChristianoKiss if you suggest an edit on my answer with that I'll accept it

Answer (score 4):

One solution for you is to put all your functions in a psm1 file and create a module. That way you can import the module and have all the commands in a nice [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Can also use

```
dir function:
```

Or to clear it up

```
dir function: | where {$_.source -ne [string]::Empty} | sort source
```

Comment: 'dir' is simply a powershell alias for Get-ChildItem. 
Its for those familar with pre-powershell Windows Command Prompt; 
other vanilla aliases for Get-ChildItem include  'ls' for Unix/Linux hacks, or 'gci' for Powershell users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am a little late. But I merged some of the other answers to set up a little routine that lets you filter the results of `Get-ChildItem function:` with a string argument. I use this because I always tend to forget the functions and aliases I include in my profile... Maybe somebody finds this helpful:

```
function fsearch {
    param([string[]] $str)
    $allfs = Get-ChildItem function: | foreach { $_.Name }
    echo "Functions"
    echo "---------"
    echo $allfs | where {$_ -match $str}
    $allalias = Get-Alias | foreach { $_.Name }
    echo ""
    echo "Aliases"
    echo "-------"
    echo $allalias | where {$_ -match $str}
}
```

Comment: PowerShell output is normally better handled as objects so that it can be reused in other commands.