# Is there a way to show all functions in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

**Is there any command to list all functions I've created in a script?**

Like i created function doXY and function getABC or something like this.

Then I type in the command and it shows:

1. Function  doXY
2. Function  getABC

Would be a cool feature^^

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Something like `cat ./things.ps1 | grep function` (MacOS/Linux) or `cat ./things.ps1 | select-string function` (Windows) won't work for you? Where your script is named `things.ps1`.

Comment: Well this solved my problem^^ Thanks

Comment: Could you write it as an answer, so I can mark my thread as answered ;)
If not - still ok xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where your script is named `things.ps1`, something like...

```
cat ./things.ps1 | grep function
```

For MacOS/Linux or...

```
cat ./things.ps1 | select-string function
```

For Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can have PowerShell parse your script, and then locate the function definitions in the resulting Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).

`Get-Command` is probably the easiest way to access the AST:

```
# Use Get-Command to parse the script
$myScript = Get-Command .\path\to\script.ps1
$scriptAST = $myScript.ScriptBlock.AST

# Search the AST for function definitions
$functionDefinitions = $scriptAST.FindAll({
  $args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]
}, $false)

# Report function name and line number in the script
$functionDefinitions |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Function '$($_.Name)' found on line $($_.StartLineNumber)!"
}
```

You can also use this to analyze the functions' contents and parameters if necessary.

Comment: How would you get the function contents without getting the entire files(s)?

Comment: @not2qubit can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ Mathias, I'm trying to do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635570/1147688). I.e. mimic the Bash internal `typset -f`.

Comment: @not2qubit I have no idea what `typset -f` is, but you can't enumerate and execute the function definitions in a file without reading the file.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen reading your comment, seeing the definition is not possible without reading the file? In Linux it is `define -f`

Comment: @Timo you can get the function definitions just fine with `ls function:`, but OP specifically asked about function definitions contained _in a file_

Answer (score 1):

This is a built-in feature as shown in the PowerShell help files.

[About_Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7)

Similar questions have been asked before. So, this is a potential duplicate of:

[How to get a list of custom Powershell functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694338/how-to-get-a-list-of-custom-powershell-functions)

Answers... Using the PSDrive feature

```
# To get a list of available functions
Get-ChildItem function:\

# To remove a powershell function
# removes `someFunction`
Remove-Item function:\someFunction
```

Or

```
Function Get-MyCommands {
    Get-Content -Path $profile | Select-String -Pattern "^function.+" | ForEach-Object {
        [Regex]::Matches($_, "^function ([a-z.-]+)","IgnoreCase").Groups[1].Value
    } | Where-Object { $_ -ine "prompt" } | Sort-Object
}
```

Or this one

[Get List Of Functions From Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967449/get-list-of-functions-from-script)

```
$currentFunctions = Get-ChildItem function:
# dot source your script to load it to the current runspace
. "C:\someScript.ps1"
$scriptFunctions = Get-ChildItem function: | Where-Object { $currentFunctions -notcontains $_ }

$scriptFunctions | ForEach-Object {
      & $_.ScriptBlock
}
```

As for this...

> Thanks, this is kind of what i want, but it also shows functions like
>   A:, B:, Get-Verb, Clear-Host, ...

That is by design. If you want it another way, then you have to code that. 
To get name of functions in any script, it has to be loaded into memory first, then you can dot source the definition and get the internals. If you just want the function names, you can use regex to get them.

Or as simple as this...

```
Function Show-ScriptFunctions
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [Alias('ssf')]

    Param 
    (
        [string]$FullPathToScriptFile
    )


    (Get-Content -Path $FullPathToScriptFile) | 
    Select-String -Pattern 'function'
}

ssf -FullPathToScriptFile 'D:\Scripts\Format-NumericRange.ps1'

# Results
<#
function Format-NumericRange 
function Flush-NumberBuffer 
#>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what i want, but it also shows functions like A:, B:, Get-Verb, Clear-Host, ...

Comment: If you wan't to get only for specific finction, where you (more or less) knows its name, use command completion (`TAB`) with: `get-content Function:`.

Comment: Careful with dot sourcing a script since this will execute the script, and will process any lines of code that are not inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

This function will parse all the functions included in a .ps1 file, and then will return objects for each function found.

The output can be piped directly into `Invoke-Expression` to load the retuned functions into the current scope.

You can also provide an array of desired names, or a Regular Expression to constrain the results.

My use case was I needed a way for loading individual functions from larger scripts, that I don't own, so I could do pester testing.

Note: only tested in PowerShell 7, but I suspect it will work in older versions too.

```
function Get-Function {
    <# 
    .SYNOPSIS 
        Returns one or more named functions from a .ps1 file without executing the file

    .DESCRIPTION
        This is useful where you have a blended file containing functions and executed instructions.

        If neither -Names nor -Regex are provided then all functions in the file are returned.
        Returned objects can be piped directly into Invoke-Expression which will place them into the current scope.

        Returns an array of objects with the following
            - .ToString()
            - .Name
            - .Parameters
            - .Body
            - .Extent
            - .IsFilter
            - .IsWorkFlow
            - .Parent

    .PARAMETER -File
        String; Mandatory
        Path of file to parse

    .PARAMETER -Names 
        Array of Strings; Optional
        If provided then function objects of these names will be returned
        The name must exactly match the provided value
        Case Insensitive.

    .PARAMETER -Regex
        Regular Expression; Optional
        If provided then function objects with names that match will be returned
        Case Insensitive

    .EXAMPLE
        Get all the functions names included in the file
            Get-Function -name TestA | select name

    .EXAMPLE
        Import a function into the current scope
            Get-Function -name TestA | Invoke-Expression

    #>
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [alias("Path", "FilePath")]
        $File
        
        , 
        [alias("Name", "FunctionNames", "Functions")]
        $Names

        ,
        [alias("NameRegex")]
        $Regex
        ) # end param

    # get the script and parse it
    $Script = Get-Command $File
    $AllFunctions = $Script.ScriptBlock.AST.FindAll({$args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]}, $false)

    # return all requested functions
    $AllFunctions | Where-Object {
        ( $Names -icontains $_.Name ) `
        -or ( $Regex -imatch $_.Name ) `
        -or (-not($Names) -and -not($Regex))
        } # end where-object
    } # end function Get-Function
```